# How can I detect whether JavaScript is disabled using prototype?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

How can I detect whether JavaScript is disabled using the prototype library? I don't want to use the `<noscript>` tag; I want to use something that prototype offers.

Comment: ok guys thx...say i want to display some text when javascript is disabled is there any alternatate tag beside <noscript>

Comment: Why don't you want to use <noscript>? That's what it's for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be pretty hard to use javascript to detect if javascript is disabled.

To answer your subquestion, if you want to emulate `<noscript>` tag behavior without using noscript, make a `<div>` element with the content you want to show to non-javascript users, and then hide it with javascript on DOMReady event. It will do exactly the same thing as a noscript tag.

```
<script type="Text/JavaScript">
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  $('simulate_noscript').hide();
});
</script>

<div id="simulate_noscript">
This is some content only users with JS disabled will see.
</div>
```

Comment: ok guys thx...say i want to display some text when javascript is disabled is there any alternatate tag beside <noscript>

Comment: Edited my original answer to answer the subquestion.

Comment: your answer sounds good can you please elaborate with an example if you dont mind.

Answer (score 5):

Since Prototype is JavaScript, you cannot use it to detect whether Javascript is disabled or not. You have to use the `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: ok guys thx...say i want to display some text when javascript is disabled is there any alternatate tag beside <noscript>

Answer (score 2):

You can't detect that javascript is disabled using javascript. Google graceful degradation, and also progressive enhancement.

Comment: ok guys thx...say i want to display some text when javascript is disabled is there any alternatate tag beside <noscript>

Answer (score 2):

You can't use JavaScript to determine if JavaScript is enabled; if it's not, then the script will never run. Instead, look to inject behaviours which require script using scripts themselves. This is a core principle of [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement#Core_principles).

Comment: ok guys thx...say i want to display some text when javascript is disabled is there any alternatate tag beside <noscript>

Answer (score 1):

Ummm if Javascript is disabled Prototype is never going to run my friend.

Comment: @Ram: yes, yes i do... Corrected.

Comment: ok guys thx...say i want to display some text when javascript is disabled is there any alternatate tag beside <noscript>

Comment: Well i suppose you could use something arbitrary like a div and then assuming js is enabled you could remove that div from the dom. If js werent enabled then it wouldnt be removed. But i dont see what your issue is with the noscript tag.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype is a JavaScript framework. If JavaScript is disabled, Prototype will not run, making a JavaScript enabled check useless.

You will need to use a `<noscript>` tag to handle situations where JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: ok guys thx...say i want to display some text when javascript is disabled is there any alternatate tag beside <noscript>

Comment: This is exactly how you would display some text if JavaScript were disabled: `<noscript>You don't have JavaScript enabled.</noscript>`

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add to the myriad of comments already that question how you are to use javascript with javascript disabled. Make sure it degrades well of course.